# Does anyone know how to calculate the following integral?

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, definite-integrals, special-functions

Consider the function (coming from a joint probability density):
$$
f(x,y) = \frac{1}{y}e^{-y-\frac{x}{y}}.
$$

I want to evaluate the definite integral (marginal):
$$
F(x) = \int_0^\infty f(x,y)\,dy.
$$

It is very hard to find a primitive in $y$, so what I did was the following workaround:
$$
\int f(x,y)\,dx = -e^{-y-\frac{x}{y}}.
$$

So if we let $g(x,y):= -e^{-y-\frac{x}{y}}$, we can write:
$$
f(x,y) = \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(x,y).
$$

Therefore:
$$
F(x) = \int_0^\infty \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(x,y)\,dy.
$$

Now the trick was: can we move the derivation out of the integral? Under what assumptions? If that were the case, we could write:
$$
F(x) = \frac{d}{dx} \int_0^\infty g(x,y)\,dy,
$$

which can be calculated in terms of Bessel functions:

$$
F(x) = \frac{d}{dx} \int_0^\infty -e^{-y-\frac{x}{y}}\,dy = -\frac{d}{dx} \big(2\sqrt{x}\,K_1(2\sqrt{x})\big).
$$

Deriving:
$$
F(x) = K_0(2\sqrt{x}) - \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\,K_1(2\sqrt{x})+K_2(2\sqrt{x}).
$$

(The last two passages according to Wolfram Alpha, for $x\ge 0$.)
The $K_n$ should be the "modified Bessel functions of the 2nd kind".

I would like to ask:

- Is it "legal" to carry the derivative out of the integral sign?
- Are the last two (Wolfram Alpha) passages correct?
- Is there any other way of obtaining $F(x)$? What is the result?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! At least one passage is then correct. Interesting thread, that one, btw.

Comment: *Does anyone know how to calculate the following integral?* - No. Not *anyone* knows how to calculate this integral. :-)

Comment: Or does "not anyone" mean "nobody"? Quantifiers in English are cumbersome...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the analysis [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/664298/a-difficult-integral?lq=1):

$$\begin{align} F(x) &= \int_0^{\infty} \frac{dy}{y} e^{-y-\frac{x}{y}}\end{align}$$

Sub $u=y+\frac{x}{y}$, then

$$y = \frac12 \left (u \pm \sqrt{u^2-4 x}\right )$$
$$dy = \frac12 \left ( 1 \pm \frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2-4 x}} \right ) du$$

Then

$$\begin{align}F(x) &= \frac1{4 x} \int_{\infty}^{2 \sqrt{x}} du \left ( 1 - \frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2-4 x}} \right )\left (u + \sqrt{u^2-4 x}\right ) e^{-u} \\ &+ \frac1{4 x} \int_{2 \sqrt{x}}^{\infty} du \left ( 1 + \frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2-4 x}} \right )\left (u - \sqrt{u^2-4 x}\right )e^{-u}\\ &= 2 \int_{2 \sqrt{x}}^{\infty} du \frac{e^{-u}}{\sqrt{u^2-4 x}}\\ &= 2 \int_0^{\infty} dv \, e^{-2 \sqrt{x} \cosh{v}}\\ &= 2 K_0(2 \sqrt{x})\end{align}$$

By using [recurrence relations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Properties) for the $K_n$, we see that the above simple expression is equivalent to the one derived using differentiation under the integral sign.

Answer (score 1):

What you have described is [differentiation under the integral sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiating_under_the_integration_sign) and the only assumption (I believe) is that $g$ and $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$ are continuous.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\infty}{1 \over y}
\exp\pars{-y - {x \over y}}\dd y}
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{\infty}{1 \over y}
\exp\pars{-\root{x}\bracks{%
{y \over \root{x}}  + {\root{x} \over y}}}\,\dd y
\\[5mm] \stackrel{y\ =\ \root{x}\expo{\theta}}{=}\,\,\,&
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{1 \over \root{x}\expo{\theta}}
\expo{-2\root{x}\cosh\pars{\theta}}\,\,
\pars{\root{x}\expo{\theta}}\,\dd\theta
\\[5mm] = &\
2\int_{0}^{\infty}
\expo{-2\root{x}\cosh\pars{\theta}}\,\,\dd\theta =
\bbx{2\on{K}_{0}\pars{2\root{x}}} \\ &
\end{align}
$\ds{\on{K}_{\nu}}$ is a *Modified Bessel Function*.
The last result is given by the [DLMF Bessel Library](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32.E9).