# Integral involving exponential and powers of $x$

Tags: probability, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, expectation

I am looking for the value of the following integral:

$$\int_u^\infty \sqrt{(x^2-a)}  \exp\left({-\left(bx^2+\frac{c}{x^2}\right)}\right)\text dx$$

I encountered this problem when trying to find the expected value of a normal PDF where the standard deviation is a function of a Rayleigh random variable.  I have seen integrals like $\int e^{-\left(bx^2+\frac{c}{x^2}\right)}\text dx$, or $\int e^{-\left(bx+\frac{c}{x}\right)}\text dx$ where the solutions involve closed form exponentials or modified Bessel functions, but I can't figure it out for the integral explained above.

Comment: what do we know about the variables?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner suppose we want to find $\int_0^\infty x e^{-x^2} (x \phi(d/\sqrt{e^2x^2+f^2}) ) dx$, where $\phi(.)$ is the standard normal PDF. I tried to reformulate it above format.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner assume that a,b,c>0

Comment: i think with $a=0$ it s possible

Comment: @tired actually I need it for positive a, but a=0 solution may help :)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/963861/a-sine-integral-problem-i/964022#964022 
for $a=0$ you may follow the same lines as i have done in my previous answer. You should also be able to construct some kind of taylor expansion out of it.