# An improper integrals related to probability, $\int_0^\infty\frac1y \exp(\frac{-x_0}y-y)\,dy$

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

How can I calculate the integral
$$\int_0^\infty{\frac1y e^{\frac{-x_0}y-y}}dy$$
in terms of well-known constants and functions?

I used some fundamental techniques of integration but got nothing.

Comment: This is an integration with respect to $y$?

Comment: yes that's true...

Comment: Did you succeed???

Comment: *I used some fundamental techniques but got nothing* - Not surprisingly, since the integral can only be expressed in terms of the special [Bessel function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function). In particular, $2K_0(2\sqrt x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u = y+x_0/y$, then

$$y=\frac12 \left (u \pm \sqrt{u^2-4 x_0} \right ) $$
$$dy=\frac12 \left (1 \pm \frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2-4 x_0}} \right ) du $$

Then the integral may be rewritten as (see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/664298/how-to-find-the-integral-int-0-infty-exp-axb-a-dx/664382#664382))

$$ \int_{\infty}^{2 \sqrt{x_0}} du \left (1 - \frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2-4 x_0}} \right ) \frac{e^{-u}}{\left (u - \sqrt{u^2-4 x_0} \right )} + \int_{2 \sqrt{x_0}}^{\infty} du \left (1 + \frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2-4 x_0}} \right ) \frac{e^{-u}}{\left (u + \sqrt{u^2-4 x_0} \right )} $$

which simplifies to

$$\begin{align}2 \int_{2 \sqrt{x_0}}^{\infty} du \, \left (u^2-4 x_0 \right )^{-1/2} e^{-u} &= 2 \int_1^{\infty} dv \, (v^2-1)^{-1/2} e^{-2 \sqrt{x_0} v}\\ &= 2 \int_0^{\infty} dt \, e^{-2 \sqrt{x_0} \cosh{t}} \\ &= 2 K_0 \left ( 2 \sqrt{x_0}\right )  \end{align}$$

where $K_0$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind of zeroth order.

Comment: thanx! nice solution...

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
\int_{0}^{\infty}{1 \over y}\,\exp\pars{-\,{x_{0} \over y} - y}\,\dd y}\ =\
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}{1 \over y}\,\exp\pars{-\root{x_{0}}\,
\bracks{{\root{x_{0}} \over y} + {y \over \root{x_{0}}}}}\,\dd y}
^{\ds{\dsc{y}=\dsc{\root{x_{0}}\exp\pars{\theta}}}}
\\[5mm]&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{1 \over \root{x_{0}}\expo{\theta}}\,
\exp\pars{-\root{x_{0}}\bracks{\expo{-\theta} + \expo{\theta}}}\,\root{x_{0}}\expo{\theta}\,\dd\theta
\\[5mm]&=2\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp\pars{-2\root{x_{0}}\cosh\pars{\theta}}\,\dd\theta
=\color{#66f}{\large 2\,{\rm K}_{0}\pars{2\root{x_{0}}}}
\end{align}

> $\ds{\,{\rm K}_{\nu}}$ is a *Bessel Function*. See $\ds{\bf 9.6.24}$
>   in [this link](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_376.htm).