# Integration by parts, exponential of a function

Tags: calculus, integration

Let  $I(q)=\int \exp\left(-\frac{f(q)}{q}\right)dq$, 
where $f(q)$ is some function of the variable $q$ with constant second derivative.

By integration by parts, one can readly see that $u=\mbox{exp}\left(-\frac{v(q)}{q}\right)$ and $dv=dq$.

Therefore, the solution of $I(q)$ could be written as follows

$$I(q)=\exp\left(-\frac{f(q)}{q}\right)q-\int q \cdot \exp\left(-\frac{f(q)}{q}\right)\left(-\frac{df(q)}{dq}q^{-1}+f(q)q^{-2}\right)dq.$$

I would like to know if the integration procedure above is correct. Thank you in advance

Comment: Definition of $I$ doesn't really makes sense: We have $\int f(x) dx = \int f(y) dy$, so the RHS of the first line is independent of $q$. Since there are no other variables, the RHS (and therefore $I$) is a constant, once you have picked a function $f$. Also you write $u = \exp\left(- \frac{v(q)}{q}\right)$. What is $v(q)$?

Comment: Also every function with constant second derivative can be written as $f(x) = a x^2 +bx + c$ for $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$. WolframAlpha can't do the integral $\int \exp\left(-a x -b - \frac{c}{x}\right) dx$, but it is calculated in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2000600/545914). Are you after that expression?

Comment: Thank you very much for confirming the calculations outlined above.

Comment: Dear Victor. I hope you are doing well. Thanks again for your help. Based on your wide experience, is it possible for you to give me your opinion on this problem? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3527752/probability-and-exponential-distribution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from typos your approach is correct.

As I mention in the comments, $I$ is constant for any $f$, so it would make more sense to write $$I(f) := \int e^{-\frac{f(x)}{x}} dx.$$

Now choosing $u(x) := e^{-\frac{f(x)}{x}}$ and $v(x) := x$, we obtain $\frac{d v(x)}{dx} = 1$, implying $dv = dx$ and with the quotient rule
$$
\frac{du(x)}{dx}
= e^{-\frac{f(x)}{x}} \cdot (-1)\left( \frac{f'(x) x - f(x)}{x^2}\right)
= e^{-\frac{f(x)}{x}} \left( \frac{f(x)}{x^2} - \frac{f'(x)}{x}\right)
$$

By partial integration we have
\begin{align}
I(f)
& = u(x) v(x) - \int v(x) u'(x) dx \\
& = x \cdot e^{-\frac{f(x)}{x}} - \int x \cdot e^{-\frac{f(x)}{x}} \left( \frac{f(x)}{x^2} - \frac{f'(x)}{x}\right) dx \\
& = x \cdot e^{-\frac{f(x)}{x}} - \int e^{-\frac{f(x)}{x}} \left( \frac{f(x)}{x} - f'(x)\right) dx
\end{align}