# Derivation of an integral that generates a Bessel function of the second kind

Tags: integration, bessel-functions, mathematica

I am working with a function where I need to solve an integral of the following form:

[image]

where $K$ is a modified Bessel function of the second kind. The image is from "Integrals and Series: Volume 1: Elementary Functions" by Prudnikov, Brychkov, and Marichev pg. 344.

I was working with the identity provided by the book, but I decided to see what I got via mathematica out of curiosity. However, when I solve the integral in mathematica I get the following solution

[image]

I am new to mathematica so I am unsure whether this is a true discrepancy (I don't think it is( and I am unable to find a derivation of the integral 2.3.16.1. I'm not a mathematician but every article I've found so far that uses 2.3.16.1 cites the lemma but does not rederive it.

Sources for the derivation would be appreciated. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: If there isn't a space between the $p$ and the $x$ in the exponent, Mathematica will interpret it as a variable called "px", which is not what you want of course.

Comment: I posted an answer, but then I realized it's basically just a slightly modified version of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/776743).